# java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [tomcat jsp]

Tags: java, jsp

I am developoing the jsp app with mysql 5+ tomcat6 +. java 1.7

When I compiled the classes with proper package structure every thing perfect.

but when I run the code I am getting error. the details are posted below

1> in *validateuser.jsp* I am using

```
<jsp:useBean id="credentials" class="com.vj.vo.UserCredentials" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="credentials" property="*"/>

<jsp:forward page="<%= nextPage %>" ></jsp:forward>

when i run the code i am getting out put as

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **`com/vj//vo/U`**serCredentials (wrong name: com/vj/vo/UserCredentials)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1206)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1178)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3442)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:231)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:709)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:680)
    org.apache.jsp.ValidateUser1_jsp._jspService(ValidateUser1_jsp.java:124)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

The packages every thing are correctly placed.

Comment: Google "NoClassDefFoundError wrong name". A number of links will come up that might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the container couldn't find your class, make sure your class is available in the server classpath, the .class file of your class must be in the WEB-INF/classes, or if the class is in a jar you must put the jar file in the WEB-INF/lib folder.